# Next.js does not pass path param

Tags: next.js

I developed an application in Next.js version 9.4.4. My folder structure is as shown below:

```
pages
[id]
  index.js
index.js
```

When I make a request to `localhost:3000/something`, it goes to the index page and when I log this information in the root index page I cannot get /something here is the code of the root index file

```js
Index.getInitialProps = (ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx.headers, ctx.pathname, ctx.url);

  return {};
};
```

The output is

```js
undefined / undefined
```

Comment: What does console.log(ctx) show?

Comment: @SterlinV this is the link to ctx output https://justpaste.it/2lr8s

Comment: @RasoulSalehi did you add getInitialProps on the current page?

Comment: @visizky I don't know what you mean by current page, in id page if you mean I added and nothing is logged there because it goes to the root index page which is where i add getIntialProps this is the code on that page. and also both have getInitialProps

Comment: what I don't know is that why /something is not passing anywhere either in id page or index page

Comment: @RasoulSalehi use a custom _app.js and try once again.

Comment: @visizky I add getInitialProps to _app.js too but I get the same result pathname was / instead of /something

Answer (score 0):

You are using dynamic routes. So your “path” would be in ctx.query (in your case: ctx.query.id)

Comment: No, it is not because of that in my case it is path param, not query param ?... so I cannot get it the initial problem is that /something is not totally working it does not go there

Comment: The getInitialProps's context does not have `headers` and `url`, so they are null. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#context-object

Comment: You have `[id]` in your project structure, and it makes a dynamic route like http://localhost:300/[id]. So your `id` would be put in `ctx.query`. Please check here https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Comment: Check out my sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-dynamic-routes-query-param-wihrh & try this url: https://wihrh.sse.codesandbox.io/something

Comment: yeah that's right, but my problem is that it never gets there to print something it goes to the home page, and there too id is undefined ofcourse it would so but I don't know why is going there

Comment: Did you disable Nextjs’s file routing (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server#disabling-file-system-routing) or have a a custom server? Please describe more by updating your question

Comment: no, I disable nothing and I don't use custom  server

Comment: Did you check my codesandbox? Is it different with your folders (you use [id], I use [slug] but they are same)?

Comment: I know that my problem is that its never gets there nothing print for your slug name is not important it goes directly to home without anything

Comment: Please provide your code on GitHub or Codesandbox for others to research